# Como alterar a fonte e cor do menu lateral do navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Olá, tenho um projeto criado como `DrawerLayout` e gostaria de customizar alterando o tipo de fonte, tamanho e cor. 
mas não consigo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Modificar a parte em vermelho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro, vai em res/values/styles e crie os seguintes temas

Para os itens do seu Navigation:

```
 <style name="NavigationItemAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#8BC34A</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed-light</item>
</style>
```

E outro caso também queira alterar a aparência dos SubTitulos:

```
<style name="NavigationSubTitleAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#8BC34A</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed-light</item>
</style>
```

lembre-se de definir o tamanho da fonte, da cor e a fonte do seu gosto.

Vá no xml da activity que está o Navigation Drawer e dentro do Navigation acrescente:

```
 app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationItemAppearance"
```

Pronto. Agora continuando caso queira alterar os SubTitulos, onde está o seu Bem-Vindo e Pré-Pago, faça da seguinte maneira:

Abra o xml onde está o menu do seu navigation e acrescente nos Subtitulos um id:

```
<item android:title="Bem-vindo"
    android:id="@+id/welcome">
```

Para todos os subtitulos que queira alterar

```
 <item android:title="Pré-Pago"
            android:id="@+id/pre_pago">
```

Na classe da sua Activity onde está o Navigation, antes do

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Acrescente:

```
    Menu myMenu = navigationView.getMenu();
    MenuItem welcome= myMenu.findItem(R.id.welcome);
    SpannableString sWelcome = new SpannableString(welcome.getTitle());
    sWelcome.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(this, R.style.NavigationSubTitleAppearance), 0, sWelcome.length(), 0);
    welcome.setTitle(sWelcome);
```

Faça o mesmo para todos os subTitulos que queira alterar

```
    MenuItem prePago= myMenu.findItem(R.id.pre_pago);
    SpannableString sPrePago = new SpannableString(prePago.getTitle());
    sPrePago.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(this, R.style.NavigationSubTitleAppearance), 0, sPrePago.length(), 0);
    prePago.setTitle(sPrePago);
```

o Resultado seria algo parecido com isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado, abraço

Comment: Mano, show de bola. E pra mudar a cor de fundo, tirar essa cor branca?

Comment: @AriMelo no xml dentro do seu NavigationView só adicione 'android:background="#FF0000" ' altera a cor pra qual deseja. Abraço

Comment: Blz, vlw consegui.